# Prevent slider from switching slides when a span element inside the slide is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having some trouble with a slide set up. I have it so that the current slide fades to the next slide when clicked. However, there is a `span` element that, when clicked, should toggle the description while staying on the same slide instead of jumping to the next which is what it does now as demonstrated in the fiddle below. How can I keep the slide still while the details `span` element is clicked?

HTML

```
<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1<span class="details">details [+]<span class="details-desc">this is the description.</span></span></div>
    <div>slide2<span class="details">details [+]<span class="details-desc">this is the description.</span></span></div>
    <div>slide3<span class="details">details [+]<span class="details-desc">this is the description.</span></span></div>
    <div>slide4<span class="details">details [+]<span class="details-desc">this is the description.</span></span></div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var $slider = $(".slider").slick({
    fade: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
})

$slider.find(".slick-slide").on("click", function(){
   $slider.slick("slickNext");
});

$("span.details").click(function(){
    $("span.details-desc").toggle("slow");
});
```

CSS

```
.slick-slide {
    background: skyblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 100px 30px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial";

}

.slick-slide:nth-child(1),
.slick-slide:nth-child(3),
.slick-slide:nth-child(5),
.slick-slide:nth-child(7),
.slick-slide:nth-child(9),
.slick-slide:nth-child(11) {
     background: teal;
}

span.details {
    bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
span.details-desc {
    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch72te2f/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stopPropagation gets it done. Please find the jsfiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ramanathanMuthuraman/txtfrag3/1/

```
$("span.details").click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
    $("span.details-desc").toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ch72te2f/3/)

Try this

```
$("span.details").on("click",function(){
    $("span.details-desc").toggle("slow");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Lnstv4/1/)

No need of additional click event listener to navigate. You can attach it in the slick settings itself

```
var $slider = $(".slider").slick({
    fade: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    autoplay:false,
    arrows:true,
    nextArrow: "div.slick-slide"

});

$("span.details").on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("span.details-desc").toggle("slow");   
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it working in your fiddle. Also, I tried applying your exact solution on [my site](http://keebs.com/dax) but it's not working for some reason. You can see the  'display' link at the bottom right corner of the first slide that loads.

Comment: @J82 can you check the fiddle link now, I have updated the fiddle. Got messed up last time.